# Bootstrap row into td overflows

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I need to insert into a table cell (TD) a bootstrap panel, like this:

```
<tr>
  <td>
     ......Here the panel......
  </td>
</tr>
```

The panel can stays over others divs (like calendar appointment). To do it, I declared the table with relative position and the note with absolute position.

It works if I insert the panel directly into the TD element, like this:
https://jsfiddle.net/0kktvptj/

But if I insert it into Bootstrap grid class as `row` and `col-sm-12`, the panel overflows `30px` on the right, like this: http://jsfiddle.net/r0L71dbv/.

I don't understand why it happens and how can I resolve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand what you want. Anyway, tables have problems with `position:relative`. When you want to use it on a `td`, make a `div` inside the `td` with `width: 100%;height:100%;position:relative;` and it works.

Is this what you wanted?

```css
.note {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
}
table.table-bordered.calendario td {
  padding: 0;
  width: 33.33%;
  height: 50px;
}
table.table-bordered.calendario td .row {
  display: inline-block;
  max-height: 45px;
  width: calc(100% + 30px);
  position: relative;
}
td .row .panel {
  border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px;
}
td .row .panel-heading {
  border-radius: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<table class="table table-bordered calendario" style="margin-top: 20px;">
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
          <div class="panel panel-success note">
            <div class="panel-heading">Titolo</div>
            <div class="panel-body">
Austin next level tilde, pug mlkshk actually helvetica banjo truffaut 
sartorial drinking vinegar mumblecore kogi. Franzen microdosing vegan, 
kale chips chillwave cliche beard.</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Not at all, because I need the note can be more then 50px height and in this case it has to stay over the table without the table cell height grows (it has to be 50px). To do it, I declared position: aboslute into "note " css class. So, the note can be over 50px and it can stay over the table (vertical overflow), but the grid have to stay 50px height. You can try it if you, in the second example (http://jsfiddle.net/r0L71dbv/), declare the height of the panel at 100px (it overflow the table vertically properly, but it also overflow the column horizontally and it's not good). Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A row should always be a child of a container or a column. The Bootstrap team make this clear in the docs. Define your layout structure, then drop in the content.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <table class="table table-bordered calendario" style="margin-top: 20px;">
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td>

            <div class="panel panel-success note " style="height: 50px; overflow: scroll; overflow-x: hidden;">
              <div class="panel-heading">Titolo</div>
              <div class="panel-body" style="overflow: hidden">Corpo del testo</div>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/r0L71dbv/10/)**

Answer (score 0):

I applied this solution: https://jsfiddle.net/rr6ju1no/1/

```css
table.table-bordered.calendario td
{
 padding: 0;
 height: 50px;
 position: relative;
}

table.table-bordered.calendario td .row
{
 width: 100%;
}

table.table-bordered.calendario td .panel
{
 overflow: scroll;
 overflow-x: hidden;
 border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px;
}

td .row .panel-heading {
  border-radius: 1px;
}

.note
{
 position:absolute;
 width:100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<table class="table table-bordered calendario" style="margin-top: 20px;">
  <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>
      <div class="row">
     <div class="col-sm-12">
          <div class="panel panel-success note " style="height: 50px;">
      <div class="panel-heading">Titolo</div>
   <div class="panel-body">Corpo del testo</div>
    </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </td>
 <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

When you resize the browser, columns maintain the same width better.